# Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView

Tags: cassandra, materialized-views, cassandra-lucene-index

I try to add new node in existing cassandra cluster. Now I have 4 nodes in cluster (2 DC). Each node has ~120 Gbytes of data. I use plugin(cassandra-lucene-index) 3.0.4 and Materialized View.

Following error occure, when I add a new node to the cluster:

> ERROR [StreamReceiveTask:3] 2016-04-18 11:50:32,597 Keyspace.java:492 - Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! messages_dump.messages
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mutation of 24032623 bytes is too large for the maxiumum size of 16777216
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.add(CommitLog.java:264) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:469) [apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
>   ...
>
> ERROR [StreamReceiveTask:3] 2016-04-18 11:50:32,598 StreamReceiveTask.java:214 - Error applying streamed data: 
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mutation of 24032623 bytes is too large for the maxiumum size of 16777216
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.add(CommitLog.java:264) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:469) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:384) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
>   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canssandra is complaining about the size of write request. Try to increase the commit log segment size

Following might help : https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207267063-Mutation-of-x-bytes-is-too-large-for-the-maxiumum-size-of-y-

Comment: I have increased commitlog_segment_size_in_mb to 64 but it has't worked. I think i have forgot to configure commitlog_archiving.properties.

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513776/mutation-of-17076203-bytes-is-too-large-for-the-maxiumum-size-of-16777216

Comment: Yes, it did. But i have another problem now.