# Using cassandra-stress to write columns of 100 MB

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-stress

I want to write partitions of 100 MB, using the stress tool in Cassandra 2.1.17. For the sake of simplicity, firstly I'm just trying to write one partition with a single column.
My stress yaml looks like this:

```
keyspace: stresscql
keyspace_definition: |
  CREATE KEYSPACE stresscql WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};

table: insanitytest
table_definition: |
  CREATE TABLE insanitytest (
        name text,
        value blob,
        PRIMARY KEY(name)
  );

columnspec:
  - name: value
    size: FIXED(100000000)


insert:
  partitions: fixed(1)             # number of unique partitions to update in a single operation
                                  # if batchcount > 1, multiple batches will be used but all partitions will
                                  # occur in all batches (unless they finish early); only the row counts will vary
  batchtype: LOGGED               # type of batch to use
  select: fixed(1)/1              # uniform chance any single generated CQL row will be visited in a partition;
                                  # generated for each partition independently, each time we visit it

queries:
   simple1:
      cql: select * from insanitytest where name = ? LIMIT 100
      fields: samerow             # samerow or multirow (select arguments from the same row, or randomly from all rows in the partition)
```

I'm running it with:

```
./tools/bin/cassandra-stress user profile=~/Software/cassandra/tools/cqlstress-insanity-example.yaml n=1 "ops(insert=1,simple1=0)"
```

Looking at the output I have:

```
Connected to cluster: Test Cluster
Datatacenter: datacenter1; Host: localhost/127.0.0.1; Rack: rack1
Created schema. Sleeping 1s for propagation.
Sleeping 2s...
Running with 4 threadCount
Running [insert, simple1] with 4 threads for 1 iteration
type,      total ops,    op/s,    pk/s,   row/s,    mean,     med,     .95,     .99,    .999,     max,   time,   stderr, errors,  gc: #,  max ms,  sum ms,  sdv ms,      mb
Generating batches with [1..1] partitions and [1..1] rows (of [1..1] total rows in the partitions)
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
insert,            1,       0,       0,       0,  3985.0,  3985.0,  3985.0,  3985.0,  3985.0,  3985.0,    4.0, -0.00000,      0,      1,      34,      34,       0,     219
simple1,           0,     NaN,     NaN,     NaN,     NaN,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0, -0.00000,      0,      1,      34,      34,       0,     219
total,             1,       0,       0,       0,  3985.0,  3985.0,  3985.0,  3985.0,  3985.0,  3985.0,    4.0, -0.00000,      0,      1,      34,      34,       0,     219


Results:
op rate                   : 0 [insert:0, simple1:NaN]
partition rate            : 0 [insert:0, simple1:NaN]
row rate                  : 0 [insert:0, simple1:NaN]
latency mean              : 3985.0 [insert:3985.0, simple1:NaN]
latency median            : 3985.0 [insert:3985.0, simple1:0.0]
latency 95th percentile   : 3985.0 [insert:3985.0, simple1:0.0]
latency 99th percentile   : 3985.0 [insert:3985.0, simple1:0.0]
latency 99.9th percentile : 3985.0 [insert:3985.0, simple1:0.0]
latency max               : 3985.0 [insert:3985.0, simple1:0.0]
Total partitions          : 1 [insert:1, simple1:0]
Total errors              : 0 [insert:0, simple1:0]
total gc count            : 1
total gc mb               : 219
total gc time (s)         : 0
avg gc time(ms)           : 34
stdev gc time(ms)         : 0
Total operation time      : 00:00:03
```

However, looking at 'nodetool tpstats' I have one successful mutation (so even though I had the timeout the mutation seems to be successful):

```
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
MutationStage                     0         0              1         0                 0
ReadStage                         0         0             33         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0              0         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0                 0
CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
HintedHandoff                     0         0              0         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0              0         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
CommitLogArchiver                 0         0              0         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                0         0             30         0                 0
ValidationExecutor                0         0              0         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0              3         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              1         0                 0
Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter               0         0             13         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                 0         0             24         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0             13         0                 0
Native-Transport-Requests         0         0            170         0                 0

Message type           Dropped
READ                         0
RANGE_SLICE                  0
_TRACE                       0
MUTATION                     0
COUNTER_MUTATION             0
BINARY                       0
REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
PAGED_RANGE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  0
```

But if I do 'nodetool flush' and 'nodetool status stresscql', this is what I get:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  131.99 KB  256     100.0%            285b13ec-0b9b-4325-9095-c5f5c0f51079  rack1
```

Since no transactions were dropped, where did the data go? From my understading I should have a value of ~100MB in the Load column, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not in the stress or the data definition but on the commit_log_segment_size_in_mb. It needs to be at least 50% larger than the data chunks. More info in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38007723/824644).